# unable to get the Audio output in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, avaudioplayer

I have a codebase which plays audio and video perfectly. I have converted that into a small framework and started using it as a part of another code. When i do this, there is no audio output.... I am unable to hear any audio output while it is being played. All the Audio player delegate methods are being called but there is no sound. The same is happening with Videos as well. All the videos are being played with out sound. Its like watching a silent movie.... Any ideas? I am using **AVAudioPlayer** for playing audio files and **MPMoviePlayerController** for playing videos.

**edit : This happens only on device. It works all fine in simulator**

Comment: How are you testing your results? Simulator, device/s??

Comment: It works fine in simulator. But the problem arises only when i run it on a device.

Comment: Have you been able to try it on multiple devices?

Comment: Another thought: Are you setting up your audio session (AVAudioSession)?

Comment: I dont think we need to set up AVAudioSession here... I am not setting it up

Comment: No Tilll... I'v tried it on iPad1 with iOS 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So stupid of me.... The problem was with the volume button on iPad. The volume button in iPad with iOS 5 has some weird bug. It does not update itself when we toggle the button between screen lock and audio output. I guess this is bug from apple and filed a bug. Hope they solve this in their next update.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across this post, I was doing the same thing, and actually AVAduioSession is needed to play audio thru speaker/headset. So having AVAudioSession is a must.

//REALLY NEED THIS LINE FOR MUSIC TO PLAY TO SPEAKER
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];

and for background playing, add these 2 lines and change setting in plist to allow background mode

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];